# Create a custom Dropdown button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is my firt question for Stackoverflow, I hope that will be ok!

I'm working on a custom [Dropdown Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgmth.png) in WPF, and I would like to add a click event on the buttons "Text1" and "Text2". I have to put this dropdown button in a DLL so I use the WPF CustomControl library. So in the perfect world, I would like to create several methods in the MainWindow.xaml.cs and send the name of the method in a class where the name of the button, the icon , the tooltip, ... that will be used in the generic.xaml to find the method to call.

I hope what I said is clear :3

The purpose of this is to have a reusable dropdown button where I can add some click event in the items when we click on it.

Here is the generic.xaml with my dropdown button :

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonDropdown}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonDropdown}">
                    <mah:DropDownButton Content="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                x:Name="DropDownButton"
                                Orientation="Vertical"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
                        <mah:DropDownButton.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}">
                                    <StackPanel.InputBindings>
                                        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
                                    </StackPanel.InputBindings>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="16"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" x:Name="PART_DropdownButton">
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </mah:DropDownButton.ItemTemplate>
                        <mah:DropDownButton.Icon>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Width="32"></Image>
                        </mah:DropDownButton.Icon>
                    </mah:DropDownButton>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The call of this custom dropdown in the MainWindow.xaml :

```xml
<CustomButton:ButtonDropdown Text="Dropdown"
                                         x:Name="ButtonDropdown"
                                         Icon="Images/Open.png"
                                         ToolTip="TOOLTIP DROPDOWN"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Here is my method OnApplyTemplate I add the line 'TextBlock textblock= GetTemplateChild("PART_DropdownButton") as TextBlock;' after the first answer.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            DropDownButton dropDownButton = GetTemplateChild("DropDownButton") as DropDownButton;
            TextBlock textblock= GetTemplateChild("PART_DropdownButton") as TextBlock;

            textblock.MouseDown += Method1;

            dropDownButton.ItemsSource = DropdownItems;
            dropDownButton.Click += ButtonDropdown_Click;
        }
```

And finally the class I have created for items in the dropdown :

```
public class DropdownItem
    {
        private string text;
        private string icon;
        private string tooltip;
        private string clickEvent;
    }
```

For the moment I have try with command and mousedown on textblock but don't work :/

**Edit :** I add the name for the textBlock and I add my method OnApplyTemplate from my ButtonDropdown.cs. The dropDownButton.click is ok but when I try to get the "PART_DropdownButton" that is null. I think because of there is not only one but several textBlock so he don't know which one to take. But that is my problem how to asign a different method on all textblock.mouseDown ? How can we put a different name on all textblock ?

Comment: You could put the textblock you're clicking in a button and bind it's command. Re template a button as a textblock or use a button template is just a transparent border.

Comment: Hi @Andy, thanks for your comment. The problem is not really to add a command or a click event but to know which item in the list of items is clicked. if there is only one item it's easy but I don't know how to get the item selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find something that works like I want !
I add an Icommand in my dropdownItem. That will contain my method.

```
public class DropdownItem
{
    private string text;
    private string icon;
    private string tooltip;
    private string clickEvent;
    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
}
```

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs I add the command I need.

```
private ICommand _command1;
    private ICommand _command2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items.Add(new DropdownItem("Text1", "Images/Open.png", "Method1", "TEST")
        {
            ClickCommand = Command1
        });
        Items.Add(new DropdownItem("Text2", "Images/Open.png", "method2", "TEST2")
        {
            ClickCommand = Command2
        });
        ButtonDropdown.DropdownItems = Items;
    }

    public ICommand Command1
    {
        get
        {
               return _command1 = new RelayCommand(Method1);
        }
    }

    public ICommand Command2
    {
        get
        {
            return _command2 = new RelayCommand(Method2);
        }
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Method 1");
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Method 2");
    }
```

And finally I add the call to this method in my generic.xaml

```
<MouseBinding Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
```

Thanks for your help, that's because of your comments and answers that I understood that I was looking in the bad direction

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Dropdown Button derives from a button control give the DropDown button a name in the xaml file e.g. "PART_DropdownButton". Then reference the name in the code behind in the OnApplyTemplate procedure. Here you can add an event handler trapping your mouse events.

```
    private DropdownButton dropdownbutton  = null;
    ...
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        dropdownbutton = base.GetTemplateChild("PART_DropdownButton") as ToggleButton;
        if (dropdownbutton != null)
        {
            dropdownbutton.MouseDown += MouseDown_Click;

        }
        else
            ....;
    }
```

Next write your event handler for MouseDown_Click.

Regards Martin

Comment: Good response, I would just show the sample XML markup showing how you add the name for the "PART_DropdownButton" context.  They already have an x:name context and I think that is what you are referring to, but also I would expand option to show you can also attach to the icon or text as well.

Comment: Hi kmcontact  and thank you for your answer. I edit my post because I think I don t explain correctly something. I already have a click event for my dropdown and I'm looking how to add a mousedown on the items in my dropdown in my exemple in the textblock. But I don't how much items I will have so this is very hard to find how to add an event. I hope my comment will help you for understanding what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance.